# Decode Javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, decoding, bookmarklet

I have quite long Javascript bookmarklet and i don't have source code anymore.
It is possible to decode it in Notepad++ but it is stil quite hard.

Any ready tool for decoding Javascript bookmarklet?

Update:
As i mentioned, i don't have source code any more. Bookmarklet have over 2000 characters and it is impossible to change anything without decoding** it.

**
Decoding = changing it to human readable and editable form.

Comment: Bookmarklets are simply url-encoded so you can use any tool that is able to perform url decode, for example [this one](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). After that you will just need to remove `javascript:` prefix

Comment: *"Any ready tool for decoding Javascript bookmarklet?"* -- a browser is the only tool you need.

Comment: See question update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Notepad++ per se, but bookmarklets are just JavaScript code that's been made to fit the rules for a URI (for instance, with percent-encoding). So you can "decode" it simply by removing the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol and passing the rest through `decodeURIComponent`:

```
var code = decodeURIComponent(bookmarktext.substring(11));
```

You can do this in your browser's dev tools console, for instance, then copy the source to Notepad++.

Comment: Can you give me some example how to use that.

Comment: @RogerWayne: What more do you need? Use `decodeURIComponent` to un-URI-encode it, then (probably) format it (say, with http://jsbeautifier.org).

Comment: That was the solution!